# Relationship between transmittance and color of the solution

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy

As I understand, transmittance is light which passes through a material and it determines the color of material (for example green solution transmits green light).
Here’s the transmission spectrum of green mineral. [image: green color]

I have a question. This compound transmits in green (550 nm) and red (650-800) regions, so why is compound green? What’s my mistake?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to make from this radiometric spectrum a photometric spectrum, involving correction to the eye spectral sensitivity.

Comment: @Poutnik unfortunately, I did not shoot the real spectrum of this mineral, this is a picture from the problem

Comment: That is, the main reason is that the eye is more sensitive to green light?

Comment: The source of data does not matter. The values can be picked from the chart.

Comment: Calculation of luminance of the RGB digital light source is 0.59*G + 0.3*R + 0.11*B.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I thought that transmittance in red is about equal to transmittance in green from plot (they’re on the same line), what’s my mistake?

Comment: @Poutnik excuse me, how to determine R, G, B, what’s it? And why can’t we determine color from original spectrum? Does this method involve correction to the eye sensitivity?

Comment: Forget RGB if you are not familiar with it. // Color is not objective parameter, but the subjective parameter of human eye+brain - see [Photopic vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photopic_vision). Only for monochromatic ( or not too far from it ) light we can directly map the wavelength and color.